# ansible.executor.playbook_executor.PlaybookExecutor is not executing playbook

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have python script to execute ansible-playbook programmatically, python calls ansible API but play is not getting executed. I believe it is because start_at_task is set to None

What should be the value of start_at_task? could somebody help me

Ansible Version: 2.9.9
Python Version: 3.6.8

This is my run_playbook method

```
def run_playbook(play_book, extra_vars, servers, inventory_path, tags='all'):
base_playbook_path = os.environ.get('PLAYBOOK_PATH',
                                    '/hom/playbooks/')
playbook_path = base_playbook_path + play_book

context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(tags=tags, connection='paramiko', remote_user='xyz', listtags=False, listtasks=False,
                                listhosts=False, syntax=False, module_path=None, forks=100,
                                private_key_file='/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/xyz.pem', ssh_common_args=None, ssh_extra_args=None,
                                sftp_extra_args=None, scp_extra_args=None, become=None, become_method=None,
                                become_user=None, verbosity=True, check=False, start_at_task=None)

loader = DataLoader()
loader.load_from_file(base_playbook_path + '.vault_pass.txt')
inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=inventory_path)
inventory.subset(servers)
variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)
variable_manager._extra_vars = extra_vars
passwords = {}
playbook = PlaybookExecutor(playbooks=[playbook_path],
                            inventory=inventory,
                            variable_manager=variable_manager,
                            loader=loader, passwords=passwords)

result = playbook.run()
return result
```

and this is simple playbook that prints the kernel version

```
---
- name: Get Kernel Versions
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: Fetch Kernel Version
      shell: cat /etc/redhat-release
      register: os_release

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ os_release.stdout }}"
```

Output:

```
PLAY [Get Kernel Versions] ****************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************

0
```

Comment: Are you sure the code isn't exiting abnormally? I would recommend `try: run_playbook(...) except Exception as e: print("run_playbook error: ", e)` or set some breakpoints in the code

Comment: @mdaniel It is returning exit code 0, Its not throwing any exception

Comment: Then the only thing I have left to suggest is [ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner#readme) which I have used with success, but I recognize that's not an answer to why your code doesn't work

Comment: @mdaniel ansible-runner works like a charm, nice wrapper for ansible API. I still wonder why my code is not working, I will be pleased If i find an answer